# Why am I getting class not found? (Laravel, PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, namespaces, service-provider

I'm trying to add a binding to the register method in my ServiceProvider but I keep getting this error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'MyApp\\Providers\\App' not found","file":"\/Users\/foobar\/Dropbox\/Staff Folders\/foobar\/htdocs\/bla\/test\/app\/MyApp\/Providers\/TestServiceProvider.php","line":14}}
```

composer.json:

```
"psr-0": {
   "MyApp": "app/"
 }
```

app/MyApp/TestServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TestServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        App::bind('payment', function()
        {
            return new \app\MyApp\Providers\Payment;
        });
    }
}
?>
```

app/MyApp/Payment.php:

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Providers;

class Payment{

    public function process()
    {
        //
    }

}


?>
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 error here.

First error (the one you showed in your question) is:

```
App::bind('payment', function()
{
    return new \app\MyApp\Providers\Payment;
});
```

Because your file is `MyApp\Providers` namespace, you need to use:

`\App::bind` instead of `App:bind` here or add `use App;` after your namespace this way:

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Providers;

    use App;
```

The second error is the one that @Bogdan mentioned. Instead of:

```
return new \app\MyApp\Providers\Payment;
```

you should use:

```
return new \MyApp\Providers\Payment;
```

but because those 2 classes are in the same namespace you can use here:

```
return new Payment;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Payment` class binding should return this:

```
return new \MyApp\Providers\Payment;
```

The namespace doesn't reflect the entire directory path, so you don't need to include `\app`. You've already added `"MyApp": "app/"` to the PSR-0 rules to map that.